# How can I avoid wrecking Dell recovery partitions when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, dell

Newbie here. :-)

I've tried reading questions and answers about installing Ubuntu on a SECOND hard drive, and although I haven't done it yet, it looks straight forward and I expect to install Ubuntu onto the second hard drive and leave XP intact  on the primary disk.

Apologies for asking this question as it is very similar to others, but I want to ensure the UBUNTU installation is as painless as possible and I don't want to mess it up.

I am nervous about messing up the various pre installed utility and recovery partitions that have been installed on the C drive of my ancient (but good) Dell Dimension 3000 desktop which runs XP Home Edition.

**QUESTION**

I want to double check that (as I understand so far ) in my computer's scenario, the GRUB file AUTOMATICALLY gets saved on the second partition of the first drive (which  holds the Windows XP OS.)   Is that right ?   and is there something I need to watch out for in my scenario?

If I've missed something here regarding the installation I would appreciate advice before I get stuck in.

**INFORMATION**

**DRIVE 0 partitions in order**

- -

  39   Mb FAT 16      Primary partition

  146  Gb NTFS        System Primary partition  ("The C Drive ")

  7.84 Mb Unallocated logical partition

  2.75 Gb FAT 32      Primary partition

**DRIVE 1** 
Ubuntu only

(P.S. The second drive will be 150gb)

Thanks in advance

Anne

Comment: The very best way to be certain not to lose data is to back it all up. You can do this with an Ubuntu install disk via "Try Ubuntu" and using various tools: gparted or Disk Utility (or Disks) to prepare the 2nd drive with an ext4 file-system , dd to backup the first drive to a file on the second drive, gzip to shrink the huge dd image on the second drive, all prior to installation. When you install choose the "something else" option and be certain that you DO NOT check format when you install.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu!I believe that instructions on how to perform all the above tasks (one by one) are available here.